# Usar dados gerados em uma função

Tags: c, escopo-de-variáveis

Olá! A função abaixo tem como objetivo, sempre que chamada, alocar um espaço de memória que servirá como um "conjunto" para usos futuros. Esses conjuntos devem ser identificados por um numero, começando em 0 para o primeiro conjunto e assim sucessivamente, porém, esse identificador precisará ser usado em outras funções. Essa identificação deverá ser retornada caso o espaço de memória for alocado corretamente (ali onde tem o return 1, deveria ser o retorno "identificador"). Como fazer algo desse tipo, começando em 0 e podendo ser usando em outras funções?

```
int criar(){
int *p;

p = malloc(50*sizeof(int));
if(p!=NULL)
    return 1;
else
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Cada espaço de memória alocado deve ter um "id"? O que será retornado e usado em outras funções é esse "id"? Existe a possibilidade de você detalhar mais o seu problema?

Comment: Eles precisam ser identificados para poderem ser operados posteriormente, por exemplo, em uma função que une dois conjuntos. Pensei no uso de variáveis estáticas de ontem pra hoje, vou testar e depois dou um feedback :)

Comment: Uma estrutura heterogênea não ajuda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o próprio endereço de memória como identificador.

```c
int criar() {
    int *p = malloc(50 * sizeof(int));
    if (p != NULL)
        return (int) p;
    else
        return -1;
}
```

Entretanto, do jeito que isso está, não parece ser uma boa ideia, pois essa função aloca uma memória e então se esquece dela, resultando em um *memory leak*. O melhor é você retornar o próprio ponteiro:

```c
int* criar() {
    return malloc(50 * sizeof(int));
}

void destruir(int *ponteiro) {
    free(ponteiro);
}
```